# How to avoid/prevent Facebook temporarily locking my account?

Tags: facebook, login

It has become frequent for Facebook to lock me out of my account when I try to log in from my PC. They ask me to verify my recent login, the exact message is:

> Please confirm your identity
>
> Recent activity may have affected your account's security, so we've locked it. We'll walk you through a few steps to confirm your identity and help you access your account. Learn more.

When I choose to do a security check, it used to give options like provide my date of birth, identify the photos of my friends, identify your recent comments etc. but now it only provides me two options; either approve my login on another computer (when I am already logged in) or provide a photo ID (this option only appears when I choose 'Confirm Identity in another way' after I select the other one).

After I verify using another computer, it unlocks my account and forces me to change the password. This has happened to me several times so I have already changed the password around 20 times. The last time this occurred, I wasn't logged in anywhere else, so I had to send a photo ID and Facebook unlocked my account within three hours. After that incident, everything was normal for one day. Now Facebook again locked my account and asks for verification. It seems I have to send a photo ID again as I am not logged in anywhere else (except in Pidgin, no, Pidgin is not the culprit here).

How can I prevent this in the future or, can I get Facebook to verify identity using registered E-mail?

**Technical details:**

- I only use Firefox to log-in to my account on a PC.
- Browser stores the cookies for the current session only, it removes
  them when I close the browser (except for some Stack Exchange sites)
- I also use a phone in which I use Opera Mini, I don't usually log out on this.
- I haven't provided my phone number, I believe this has something to do with the frequent lock outs.

Comment: Try to set Firefox to keep cookies (and not delete them after every session) just for test. Certain services (such as for example Google Recaptcha) interpret absence of cookies as a suspicious activity and think that you may be a bot. Not sure if this is gonna work but if you could try this just to see if this is to blame.

Comment: @papakias My browser only keeps cookies from certain wesites like Stack Exchange sites. I have seen that behaviour of Google, and I am not gonna save those cookies, certainly not from Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot stop locking account permanently, because whenever something smell suspicious to Facebook, they immediately locked the account and ask user to verify the identity for security purpose. Sometimes Facebook also locked an account when one or more *friends* report about the account.

Here are some tips to keep an account secure and avoid locking:

- [Keeping Your Account Secure](https://www.facebook.com/help/235353253505947/?ref=u2u)

  - add a phone number and verify it
  - verify you email address
  - turn on notification about your account, security and privacy
  - set the get alerts about unrecognized logins
  - choose 3 to 5 friends to contact if you get locked out
- Complete you profile with all valid data
- [Avoid Spam and Scams](https://www.facebook.com/help/1584206335211143/?ref=u2u)

If still you face the issue then [report a problem to Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/1126628984024935?helpref=hc_global_nav).